# How can I get a value from another table and save it to another table in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Jobs Table Which has the columns: 
jobid, jobposition, jobdesc, and schoolname
I have an Admins Table which has the columns:
id, name, email, password, and school

now, I already have an Admin account and after I log in, I want to store values into the Jobs table: so I would request for the jobposition and jobdesc but I want the schoolname to get the same value as the 'school' column in the Admins table.

This is my jobcontroller.php in the store function

```
    public function store(Admin $admin)
{
    job::Create([
    'jobposition' => request('jobposition'),
    'jobdesc' => request('jobdesc'),
    'schoolname' => $admin->school;
    ]);

    //return

}
```

I have use both Admin and Job models, is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are logging through your admin credentials with respective of admins table then I would suggest you can have `Auth::user()` something like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    //Get logged in user -- Admin table
    $admin = Auth::user();

    job::Create([
    'jobposition' => request('jobposition'),
    'jobdesc' => request('jobdesc'),
    'schoolname' => $admin->school;
    ]);

    //return

}
```

Comment: so I used $admin = Auth::admin();
it returns "method admin does not exist"

Comment: It will be `Auth::user()` as mentioned there.

Comment: i have two people who can log in, a user and an admin. A user cannot add into the jobs database, only an admin can. so I cannot use Auth::user()

Comment: How admin logs in? How you are identifying that this user is admin?